# BFS? - find all paths from s to t that have at most a certain length

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Given an undirected (connected) graph, I want to *list* all paths from `s` to `t` that use at most `k` edges.

A naive approach would, of course, just take a BFS and stop it after `k` steps from `s` (or a DFS where we cut off after `k` steps), reporting whatever paths end up in `t`.

I was wondering whether there was a more sophisticated way to do this?

Comment: Are cycles allowed? Can you travel to the same vertex twice?

Comment: @MukulGupta Yes and yes.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how you could use a BFS or DFS here. Since you need to enumerate all possible paths from `s` to `t`, then you cannot solve it without some recursive search. Moreover, generally the amount of paths would be exponential in `k`, so do not hope for any major asymptotic complexity improvements.

To my mind, only pruning can slightly help you.
Here are two ways of pruning worth mentioning:

---

The first one is the **meet-in-the-middle** approach.

Instead of searching for all vertices at distance `<= k` from vertex `s`, find two groups of vertices: at distance `<= k/2` from `s`, and at distance `<= k/2` from `t`. Just launch two searches (BFS or recursive) to get them. Finally, merge the results: for each common vertex `v` in these two sets, take all pairs of paths from `s` to `v` and paths from `t` to `v` (reversed), and output the joined path.

The exact approach described above would list some paths several times. In order to fix it, store paths of each particular length in a separate list. Then merge paths of each length separately.
Note that if you want to get only simple paths (i.e. no vertex repeated), then the MitM approach is **not** applicable.

---

The second way is to use distance estimates, similar to how [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) does it. Suppose that you have guaranteed lower bounds on distance from any vertex `v` to destination vertex `t`. Then you can drop any partial path from `s` to `v` if it surely cannot be continued to a sufficiently short full path from `s` to `t`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a bfs that you need, because to get all the paths you must keep the adjacent vertices that you already visited.

With the following graph:

- 0->1
- 0->0
- 1->1

All the paths from 0 to 1 that contain 2 steps are [0,0,1],[0,1,1]

The naive solution is to keep a list of the nodes active at each step (with duplicates). To go from stem i to i+1, create a new list with all the adjacent vertices for each vertex (do not remove duplicates).